# Are AWS Cloudfront custom error pages slow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a single page application hosted on S3 and served with Cloudfront. Everything works fine, but I am trying to improve the performance of the first load of the application by caching all files on Cloudfront. Right now all files are served very quickly except one: the page HTML. There is only one HTML file (/index.html), that is served every time the file cannot be found on the origin (S3) by using a custom error page on Cloudfront. This file is served, for example, on the root of my domain.

I setup the Error Caching Minimum TTL of the custom error page to cache the response for 1 whole day (86400 seconds), as the image shows.
[Cloudfront customer error page settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sb1KH.png)

This cache configuration, however, seems to have no effect. Everytime the URL is not present on the origin (and S3 returns the status 403), the response is correct, but Cloudfront indicates a Miss on the x-cache header and takes around 500ms to respond. If the file is requested by the path "/index.html" on my domain, Cloudfront indicates a Hit on the x-cache header and responds in 20ms.

The index.html file has a cache control header set for a max age equal to the Cloudfront error caching minimum TTL.

Am I missing something or Cloudfront custom error pages are just slow?

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue. My theory is that because S3 is returning dynamic content for the error page, CloudFront can't actually cache the custom error page because it is checking the origin (S3) every time.

Answer (score 3):

There's a workaround for this problem by setting the S3 bucket policy to include `"s3:ListBucket"` on the bucket resource itself. For example,

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity INSERT-CLOUDFRONT-OIA-ID"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::EXAMPLE-BUCKET"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The difference is that error pages will then have a 404 HTTP status code (from S3) instead of 403 (from S3), which means [CloudFront will actually respect the cache TTL of the custom error page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/HTTPStatusCodes.html#HTTPStatusCodes-cached-errors) so it won't hit origin (S3) again.

After this change I was seeing 10ms response times on the non-root `/` routes on CloudFront.

**Important side effect** of this change is that people could in theory view your bucket's directory listings with the [ListObjects API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjects.html) e.g. `http://EXAMPLE-BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/?delimiter=/`, so it is important to use [OAI (Origin Access Identity)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html) to protect the S3 bucket to be only accessible from CloudFront (where the ListObjects URL will not work).

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing about TTFB (Time to first byte) about 800ms from Tier 100 (US, EU region) Cloudfront from India client/user.

#### Solution 1 - Cloudfront functions

With help of Cloudfront functions, this value reduced to about 180ms. The latency is same as the time taken for the default index.html.

Here is the code for it.

```
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request;
    var uri = request.uri;

    if (!uri.includes('.')) { // update with your own logic
        request.uri = '/index.html';
    }
    return request;
}
```

This will reduce the TFFB, but will start costing you on the total number of requests to CloudFront. $0.10 per million invocations.

#### Solution 2 - Generate routes

From the application, if we have a list of routes the user can possibly go to, you can create s3 directories and copy over the index.html . This approach requires you to have control over the app.